# Grab different column value after grouping by and aggregating a certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a table like so

```
CREATE TABLE Records (Event VARCHAR, Severity INT, Location VARCHAR)
```

I'd like to be able to grab the Event name and location of the row with the lowest severity. How could I achieve this?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Unless you *really* want a `varchar(1)`, but then why not use a `char(1)`?

Comment: Do you assume that there is only one row with the lowest severity?

Answer (score 2):

Using top(1), limit(1) etc... you will get only **one** record with the lowest severity, but in case there are 2 of them you will lose the second.
I suggest you to use a nested query as follows:

```
from records r
where Severity = (
    select min(severity) 
    from records
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple method:

```
select top (1) r.*
from records r
order by r.severity;
```

If you want all rows in the event of ties, then use:

```
select top (1) with ties r.*
```